# Assigning list as value to many to many filed in my model django

Tags: django, many-to-many, variable-assignment

I have a table with many to many to field, Now i have a variable with nested list(list with multiple list ex. [[],[],[]] like this) i want to put  that variable  as values  to my many to many field by obj.fieldname.set() or .add() method . 
But it is showing error unhashable list type .
Anyone can help??
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post some code as to what you tried and the stach trace as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542778/how-to-store-a-list-into-many-to-many-field-in-django-model

Comment: you can check my code here