# how to store a list into many-to-many field in django model

Tags: python, database, list, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model class dietplan in which there is a many-to-many field named breakfast. In my view.py I have done some calculation and get a value for breakfast as nested list i.e. [['abc','asda'],['val3','val4']]

I want to these all 4 list in my many to many field.

This is my code:

MODELS.PY\

```py
class Dietplan(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dietplan_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    breakfast = models.ManyToManyField('Meal', 
    related_name='breakfast_meal_name',)
    snacks1 = models.ManyToManyField('Meal', 
    related_name='snacks1_meal_name',)
    lunch = models.ManyToManyField('Meal', related_name='lunch_meal_name',)
    snacks2 = models.ManyToManyField('Meal', 
    related_name='snacks2_meal_name',)
    dinner = models.ManyToManyField('Meal', related_name='dinner_meal_name',)
    calories_slab = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

VIEWS.PY

```py
def dietplan(request):
    d = Dietplan.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
    d.dietplan_name = 'abc'
    d.breakfast.set(','.join(breakfast))
    d.save()
```

Showing unhashable list type error

Comment: When pasting code, please ensure to preserve indentation.

Comment: Thank I'll  take care of it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Meal objects already exists, first you should get them from their name. You can try something like:

```
meal_names = 'meal1 meal2 meal3'.split()
meal_objects = []
for name in meal_names:
    meal_objects.append(Meal.objects.get(name=name))
```

once you have collected them, you can append them in your manytomany relation as follow:

```
d = Dietplan.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
d.breakfast.add(*meal_objects)  # unpacking meal_objects list as positional arguments
d.save()
```

Note: I have not tested the code in django, let me know this raise some errors.

Comment: I have a variable  breakfast  which is storing meal_names .. ex breakfast = [['milk', 'bread'],['milk','omlet']]

Comment: Main problem is i have a variable with values of list type i want to store that variable in many to many field

Comment: are milk, omlet and bread different meals? Why are they in nested lists? Perhaps you should amend your question to better explain what you are trying to achieve, because this is not really clear.

Comment: Breakfast  is many to many field so i can store multiple meals there by admin panel  i am able to select and save but from views first i have to find out what are the meals so i stored them into a list form then tried to sa ve ... i try to store meals in string form also but it not saving .... then error is int base '10' value not found

Comment: Breakfast  is many to many field so i can store multiple meals there by admin panel  i am able to select and save but from views first i have to find out what are the meals so i stored them into a list form then tried to sa ve ... i try to store meals in string form also but it not saving .... then error is int base '10' value not found

Comment: You should update your question with the Meal model so we can better understand how to interact with. In particular it would be useful to get an identifying field (i.e. having a unique constraint) so we can query it